# eBay Confirming Publish Offer on Sandbox Ebay

Tags: ebay-api, ebay-sdk, ebay-net-sdk

I'm able to successfully post to the Publish Offer API endpoint. It returns a 200 status.

However when I go to the sandbox.ebay.com and search for the product I can't find it.
It says 1 product found but it does not appear as a listed item.

https://www.sandbox.ebay.com/sch/i.html?&_from=R40&_trksid=p2334524.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.XPRC%20Apple%20Watch.TRS0&_nkw=PRC%20Apple%20Watch&=&LH_TitleDesc=0&_odkw=PRC%20App%20Watch

Is there another API I need to call?
I am using this eBay reference tool: https://developer.ebay.com/my/api_test_tool?index=0&api=inventory&call=offer__POST&variation=json

This is the post body:

```
{
    "sku": "ddtest1",
    "marketplaceId": "EBAY_US",
    "format": "FIXED_PRICE",
    "listingDescription": "<ul><li><font face=\"Arial\"><span style=\"font-size: 18.6667px;\"><p class=\"p1\">Test listing - do not bid or buy&nbsp;<\/p><\/span><\/font><\/li><li><p class=\"p1\">Built-in GPS.&nbsp;<\/p><\/li><li><p class=\"p1\">Water resistance to 50 meters.<\/p><\/li><li><p class=\"p1\">&nbsp;A new lightning-fast dual-core processor.&nbsp;<\/p><\/li><li><p class=\"p1\">And a display that\u2019s two times brighter than before.&nbsp;<\/p><\/li><li><p class=\"p1\">Full of features that help you stay active, motivated, and connected, Apple Watch Series 2 is designed for all the ways you move<\/p><\/li><\/ul>",
    "availableQuantity": <availableQuantity>,
    "quantityLimitPerBuyer": <quantityLimitPerBuyer>,
    "pricingSummary": {
        "price": {
            "value": 0.99,
            "currency": "USD"
        }
    },
    "listingPolicies": {
        "fulfillmentPolicyId": "78842674011",
        "paymentPolicyId": "61019561011",
        "returnPolicyId": "61019560011"
    },
    "categoryId": "178086",
    "merchantLocationKey": "Store1",
    "tax": {
        "vatPercentage": 10.2,
        "applyTax": true,
        "thirdPartyTaxCategory": "Electronics"
    }
}
```

Post Header

```
Authorization:Bearer <OAUTH_token>
Accept:application/json
Content-Type:application/json
Content-Language:en-US
```